# Как преобразовать view в  bitmap  до отрисовки?

Tags: android, java

Добрый день!
Вообще не понимаю как мне быть 
view создается только для того, чтобы получить bitmap и ни для чего больше. Я конечно же поискал, но вот только все, что я находил не работает :(
Сейчас есть вот это

```
Bitmap bitmapMarker = getBitmapMarker(context,object);
        Bitmap arrowBitmap = getBitmapArrow(context,object);

        View v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.marker,null);
        v.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        ((ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.arrow)).setImageBitmap(arrowBitmap);
        ((ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.forNumber)).setImageBitmap(bitmapMarker);

        //падает вот тут, со словами width and height must be > 0
        Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap( v.getLayoutParams().width, v.getLayoutParams().height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        // мне понятно, что ширина и высота должны быть не нулевыми, но как это сделать, ведь view еще не отрисовалось
        Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
        v.measure(v.getLayoutParams().width, v.getLayoutParams().height); 
        v.layout(0, 0, v.getLayoutParams().width, v.getLayoutParams().height);
        v.draw(c);
```

был такой вариант, но тут падало тоже, тем, но что-то еще не существует
***java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:529)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)***

```
v.measure(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getLayoutParams().width, v.getLayoutParams().height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
        v.layout(0, 0, v.getMeasuredWidth(), v.getMeasuredHeight());
        v.draw(c);
```

Comment: Я немного не догоняю. А что вы пытаетесь сделать?

Comment: Объясните все-таки чего вы пытаетесь достичь, есть подозрение что этого можно добиться другими способами и проще.

Comment: @Dimanoid уже два года прошло, проблема давно решена :)

Answer (score 2):

Вот пример того как это можно сделать.

```
View view = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.marker, null, false);
final RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
view.setLayoutParams(lp);
((ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.arrow)).setImageBitmap(arrowBitmap);
((ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.forNumber)).setImageBitmap(bitmapMarker);
final DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
final int width = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(metrics.widthPixels, View.MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
final int height = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(metrics.heightPixels, View.MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
/**
 * Если размер не важен то:
 *  final int width = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
 *  final int height = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED); 
 */
view.measure(width, height);
view.layout(0, 0, view.getMeasuredWidth(), view.getMeasuredHeight());

Bitmap screenshot = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getMeasuredWidth(), view.getMeasuredHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(screenshot);
view.draw(canvas);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>       //падает вот тут, со словами width and height must be > 0
>             Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(
> v.getLayoutParams().width,
> v.getLayoutParams().height,
> Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
>             // мне понятно, что ширина и высота должны быть не нулевыми, но
> как это сделать, ведь view еще не
> отрисовалось
```

---

```
Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap( 100, 100, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
```